# Access: insert multiselect box values into database

Tags: ms-access

I have a form setup in Access that contains many input fields and dropdown boxes.
This form doesnt contain an insert button. I just click on 'add record' at the bottom of the window.

Now I`ve add a multiselect box which contains multiple values.

I want the form to insert the selected values from the multiselect box along with all values from the other input fields in the same row if possible.

For example; the column that holds the multiselectbox values needs to contain 1,2,3

Another option is to store these values in a different table as long as I can join both tables when generating reports later on.

Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: What version of Access are you using? The answer changes based on that in this situation.

Comment: We use both 2003 and 2013 (mixed environment)

Comment: ok, cool, 2016 would have a special datatype for you but since not...How do you populate the list box? Can you add another table to store the multiple values or do you need to store them concatenated together in your original table?

Comment: The box is populated using a table that holds the values. Its not a problem to add another table, as long as I can link them together when selecting data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Either way requires a table structure like this (called a many-to-many relationship):

[image]

Option 1 is to make a subform which has a combobox on it. The subform is bound to this cross reference table `ParentTableLookups` and the combobox's control source is `ParentTableLookups.LookupStoreValue` and Rowsource is the `Lookups` table.

This is much less code and doesn't require a save button however it does mean that in order to see the things a user did not select they need to open the combobox. Maybe not quite as visually complete as the listbox.

Option 2 is to use the same table structure but instead of a subform you fill in a listbox on your parent form from `Lookups`. Then you iterate over `ParentTableLookups` where `ParentTableLookups.ParentTableId` = your current record and for each `ParentTableLookups.LookupStoreValue` you select that in the listbox.

In the parent form's `AfterUpdate` and `AfterInsert` records you need to repopulate `ParentTableLookups` based on the selected listbox values. You can create the records using DAO easily.